# Why can I not use different camera sources within Opencv and Kivy?

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to understand why I can not use different sources as the video capture device within Opencv and Kivy. Currently I am trying (and failing) to implement the kv language to place my camera widget. This is what I have currently:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty


# 1.2 other libraries needed that are not a part of kivy
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import serial

# 2. Variables (declared after structural code is done)

# 3. tabpanelkv kv file
Builder.load_string("""

<tabpanelkv>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Cameras'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            cols: 1
            GridLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 1.5
                rows: 1
                cols: 1
                KivyCamera:
                    source: 
            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                cols: 2
                Button:
                    text: 'Cam2'
                Button:
                    text: 'Cam3'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Diagnostics'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 4
            cols: 10
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
""")

class KivyCamera(Image):
    source = ObjectProperty()
    fps = NumericProperty(30)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._capture = None
        if self.source is not None:
            self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.source)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / self.fps)

    def on_source(self, *args):
        if self._capture is not None:
            self._capture.release()
        self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.source)

    @property
    def capture(self):
        return self._capture

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr"
            )
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.texture = image_texture

# 5. tabpanelkv class
class tabpanelkv(TabbedPanel):
    pass

# 6. Main Class
class MainClass(App, GridLayout):
    def build(self):
        return tabpanelkv()

# 7. Main Loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass().run()
```

Also I understand that this code is not as optimized as it should be. I am working on the basic running code before I begin to implement more. My hope is that I can have 3 external USB cameras on the main screen and a bunch of other widgets on the other tab. But for some reason the code is outputting as an error this:

```
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 18:
 ...
      16:                cols: 1
      17:                KivyCamera:
 >>   18:                    source: 2
      19:            GridLayout:
      20:                rows: 1
 ...
 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 700, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/image.py", line 257, in texture_update
     filename = resource_find(self.source)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/resources.py", line 52, in resource_find
     if filename[:8] == 'atlas://':
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like your specific issue is probably relating to overriding the normal meaning of `source`, as the kivy image widget already has this. Try using  a different name.

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: Replace your example with the new code and error, then

Comment: I must've missed a use of source somewhere. I will post working code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to inclement in the comments, the code now works and he also asked me to re-post the working code. Here:

```
# 1. Import necessary libraries
# 1.1 Kivy libraries and imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty


# 1.2 other libraries needed that are not a part of kivy
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import serial

# 2. Variables (declared after structural code is done)

# 3. tabpanelkv kv file
Builder.load_string("""

<tabpanelkv>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Cameras'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            cols: 1
            GridLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 1.5
                rows: 1
                cols: 1
                KivyCamera:
                    cam: 2
            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                cols: 2
                Button:
                    text: 'Cam2'
                Button:
                    text: 'Cam3'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Diagnostics'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 4
            cols: 10
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
            Button:
                text: 'Button'
""")

class KivyCamera(Image):
    cam = ObjectProperty()
    fps = NumericProperty(30)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._capture = None
        if self.cam is not None:
            self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / self.fps)

    def on_cam(self, *args):
        if self._capture is not None:
            self._capture.release()
        self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam)

    @property
    def capture(self):
        return self._capture

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr"
            )
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.texture = image_texture

# 5. tabpanelkv class
class tabpanelkv(TabbedPanel):
    pass

# 6. Main Class
class MainClass(App, GridLayout):
    def build(self):
        return tabpanelkv()

# 7. Main Loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass().run()
```